# Is there a way to get a currently active Wizard in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, wizard, workbench

I want to check if a specific Wizard is currently open.

This is how i would check if a specific view is currently open:

```
final IWorkbenchWindow bench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

    if (bench.getActivePage().findView(ExampleView.ID) == null) {

        ...

    }
```

Is there a similar way to do this for Wizards?

The method

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows()
```

specifically states that it does not return wizards, but there has to be some way to get them, right?

Comment: Wizards are Modal dialogs - no other UI code will run while they are open. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I've got a problem where when pressing "finish" my wizard opens an editor and that editor sometimes opens a popup window. I don't want that popup window to show up if the wizard is still open. Because it leads to a very odd interaction between the wizard and the popup where you have to close the popup and then click finish a second time in the wizard for it to actually finish for some reason.

Comment: Using `Display.asyncExec` to run the code opening the editor will usually delay the open until after the dialog closes.